# How to use a hyphenated user-name with postgres in sql-interactive-mode?

Tags: sql-interactive-mode, postgresql

I have the following configuration in emacs init files to set a variable (`user`) to the current Unix login user:

```
(setq sql-postgres-login-params
      `((user :default ,user-login-name)
        (database :default ,user-login-name)
    (server :default "127.0.0.1")
        (port :default 5432)))
```

With this, I was able to login into PostgreSQL databases with the Unix login user as the default database user. However, this stops working when the Unix user name contains dashes `-`, and needs to be double-quoted. For example, in PostgreSQL, when the unix user is `myuser`, it's OK to use it directly as the database user name. However, when the user name is `my-user`, it needs to be quoted as `"my-user"` to be used as a user name (or database name). My question is:

*How can I make the `user-login-name` in the above example quoted?*

e.g. if `,user-login-name` is `my-user`, how do I use `"my-user"` instead?

I am not familiar with elisp, and the below is the best I can come up with (concatenating with `"\""`s). But database login still fails.

```
(setq sql-postgres-login-params
      `((user :default ,(concat "\"" user-login-name "\"") )
        (database :default ,(concat "\"" user-login-name "\"") )
        (server :default "127.0.0.1")
        (port :default 5432)))
```

Comment: So if using `psql` on the command line, for instance, you would say `psql --username='"my-user"'` ?

Comment: Are you getting an error message with the failure?  Maybe in the `*Messages*` buffer?  If so, please copy it to the question.

Comment: In any case, if you could provide an example of a *working* `psql` command, that would be very useful.

Comment: I think the scope of this question is *very specifically* about `sql-postgres`, so I've made some edits.  FYI as far as elisp and strings go, there's nothing wrong with your `concat` usage (or you could alternatively use `format`). I *suspect* none of that is actually relevant to your problem, though (and indeed that it's potentially causing *additional* problems to add those quotes in that context).

Comment: @phils, Thanks! Your comments and answer are exactly right. `psql` works fine on the command line. And there was no errors in *Message*. Adding the code in your answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what you've asked, but is possibly the actual problem.  Does it help?

```el
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'my-sql-interactive-mode-hook)

(defun my-sql-interactive-mode-hook ()
  "Custom interactive SQL mode behaviours.  See `sql-interactive-mode-hook'."
  ;; Product-specific behaviours.
  (when (eq sql-product 'postgres)
    ;; Allow symbol chars and hyphens in database names in prompt.
    ;; Default postgres pattern was: "^\\w*=[#>] " (see `sql-product-alist').
    (setq sql-prompt-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*=[#>] ")
    ;; Ditto for continuation prompt: "^\\w*[-(][#>] "
    (setq sql-prompt-cont-regexp "^\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\|-\\)*[-(][#>] ")))
```

n.b. This was the only issue I could see when I did a test with a hyphenated username, and it doesn't prevent login as such, but it *does* cause problems (which include the login apparently taking a long time, and the SQLi buffer not showing a prompt, which might very well seem like a login failure).

Comment: n.b. I believe you'll want to revert your `sql-postgres-login-params` changes before testing.